# Variable being replaced by whitespace

Tags: shell, cygwin

I am using shell script on cygwin terminal to copy few lines in a file.

```
mkdir CPM_WORKAREA
touch ~/.ssh/config
echo "Host gerrit.epk.ericsson.se" >> ~/.ssh/config
echo "HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dss" >> ~/.ssh/config
echo "Hostname 136.225.198.208" >> ~/.ssh/config
echo User $signumid >> ~/.ssh/config
echo "PubKeyAuthentication yes" >> ~/.ssh/config
echo "IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

In the above file $signumid is a variable and am trying to set its value through the command line using:

```
    sh script1.sh signumid="john"
```

But when the above script is being run, it copies the lines in config file, but leaves blank space in place of signumid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignments must precede the command, otherwise the string `signumid=john` is understood as a parameter to the script.

```
signumid="john" sh script1.sh
```

Comment: What's the difference between sh script1.sh signum="john" and signum= "john" sh script.sh